# How do I make Label1 appear if a TextBox has the correct password, and make Label2 appear if it does not?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Okay the title states it all, so my current code is this:

```
If TextBox1.Text = ("mypassword") Then
    Form2.Show()
End If
Timer1.Start()

Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

If TextBox1.Text = ("mypassword") Then
    Label1.Visible = True
End If
```

How do I make my program check if the TextBox1.text contains "mypassword" and if it does it displays Label1 which contains "approved" and if it doesn't say "mypassword" it = label2 and displays "not approved". Obviously this is dumbed down so the question makes sense.

Comment: Write your question title out in words please. No code should be in the title. This will help make your question more understandable

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 Changed

Comment: much more understandable :)

Comment: You should read [ask] to learn how to write better titles and questions (and *why* thats important), and also take the [tour] to learn what you should do when someone takes the time to decipher your post and help you with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember of VBA, this should work:

```
If TextBox1.Text = ("mypassword") Then
    Label1.Visible = True
Else
    Label2.Visible = True
End If
```

But you might want to consider whether you really want to use two labels for this. I'd recommend using one label and changing its .Text value:

```
If TextBox1.Text = ("mypassword") Then
    Label1.Text = "Approved"
Else
    Label1.Text = "Not Approved"
End If
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I have tried that so many times and I guess because I was putting else after the approved portion of the code it wasn't working. Thanks

Comment: @Essence glad it worked! If an answer solves your problem, upvote it and click the checkmark to mark it as the official answer.

Comment: I have tried that many times but it says it won't publicly count and then it just resets to 0.

Comment: OK thats probably because you're a new user. Don't worry, you'll eventually be able to upvote things. Thanks for trying anyway. Good luck with your project!